# How to package folders and use it like library in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I want to package Model folder and services folder in Angular 5. By doing this I want to use them like other libraries in node_modules. Could you please introduce good links to do this, guys? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a library with the latest version of CLI.

Update it with `npm install @angular/cli -g`

Then, in your project folder simply do `ng generate library my-lib --prefix=my-lib`

You will want to set a prefix, since angular cli will update all your configs with the values for this and create boilerplates.

I recommend doing this **on a newly generated project** after updating CLI since there are issues when using earlier projects generated by angular CLI. After that you can paste in your existing ts files and try compiling them.

[Here is a link to a tutorial](https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e)

Now packaging these is not completely trivial if you are not used to doing it. Docs are not complete. E.g. the compiler has problems with `index.ts` files which do named re-exports. Also it is likely you will run into issues when you want to compile scss for it.